# sympy.stats: TypeError: 'NegativeInfinity' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, sympy, probability

Suppose I have two uniformly distributed numbers x_1 and x_2, drawn from the range [0,1].  What is the probability that their distance |x_1 - x_2| is larger than, say, 1/2?

Here's what I've done:

```
import sympy
from sympy import Abs
from sympy.stats import * 
print (sympy.__version__)

x_1 = sympy.stats.Uniform("x_1", 0, 1)
x_2 = sympy.stats.Uniform("x_2", 0, 1)

# A = P(abs(x_1-x_2)>1/2) 
# A = P(sympy.functions.elementary.complexes.Abs(x_1-x_2)>1/2) 
A = P((x_1-x_2)**2>1/4)   
print (A)
```

Any of these three attempts leads to:

```
#TypeError: 'NegativeInfinity' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I don't know if this is a bug or have I done something wrong?

Comment: Just to be clear, this error is produced from deep inside `sympy.stats.P`.  I avoid it if I give a `numspamples` value.  (That was just a guess).  The traceback should provide enough information if you want to dig into the code and find out why it's raising this error.  (`sympy` code is not perfect!).

Comment: I'm wondering how to get more info on that.  Searching for "sympy numspamples" on the web yields nothing. Did I type something wrong?  Do you have more info?

Comment: What did i just write?  The traceback looks like it's evaluating some sort of series, and has problems evaluating an inf (or -inf) number of terms.  We have to understand how it is evaluating this probability.  Apparently some expressions are easier to evaluate than others, at least with the methods it uses.

Comment: Yes, I just don't know what a numspamples value is.

Comment: I just tried `numsamples=10` and other numbers.  The larger the number the longer it took.  I'm a bit rusty on probability, but looks like `x_1` is a uniform sample generator.  To get a probability we have to either generate a finite number of samples to get a numeric approximation, or do some sort of theoretical/algebraic computation to estimate an infinite number of samples.  The theory is simple for some distributions, impossible for others.

Comment: Long story short, its a choice with polynomials. sympy.polys chose to have `Poly(0, x).degree() == -oo`. But sympy.stats does not know about this. This can be fixed but there is still another bug that produces incorrect results. See [a very similar GitHub issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/19941).